# Customized User Registration Form

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-fapi, user-registration

i have made user-register.tpl.php file. And i have set many text field in that.
But now i need that.... 
i want to store the users information to the database. bcz i have created the customized registration page, so i need that my text field values should be store in the database.
like this.......

```
Username:    <input type="text" name="myuser" id="myuser" />
```

Now i want to store the username, which will entered in this myuser text filed.

---

Nitish
[Panchjanya Corporation](http://www.panchjanyacorp.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="acc_info_form">
  Username:    <input type="text" name="myuser" id="myuser" /><br/>
  First Name:    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br/>
  <input  type="submit"  value="Save"/>
</form>
```

index.php

```
   //Here you have to write database connection and then
    <?PHP  if ( $_POST){  ?>
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (myuser, name) VALUES('".$_POST['myuser']."',".$_POST['name']."' )") or die(mysql_error());
    <?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: Yes...i think, i was making it complicated, but in the fact was it is easy. So thanks...

Comment: this solution is vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to use at least `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitize the POST input before it is inserted into the query.